# deciphering between statistical tests

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, wilcoxon-signed-rank, mcnemar-test

I want would like to test if the mean iron
concentrations were higher at delivery time in the vaxx
group compared to the placebo ,what hypothesis test would i use

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! You've tagged the question with [tag:wilcoxon-signed-rank] and [tag:mcnemar-test]. What do you think of those tests?